# Can we not use the term object while defining encapsulation in OOP?

Tags: oop

I have read a definition of encapsulation which  stated that "Encapsulation is the wrapping of data  and functions into a single unit called **class**" .My question is that can we not use the term **object** instead of **class** in the definition because at last objects are created using the classes and objects only encapsulate data and functions inside them?

Comment: The objects contain the datas and methods defined in the class. Their visibility (encapsulation) **public**, **private**, **protected**, etc... are defined in the class, not in the object. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every class has objects.

We can have static classes that have no objects.

If the definition were changed to use the word "object", these classes would not be covered. With "class", both static and non static classes are covered.

Even if a class is not static, it could have static data and functionality, again the term class is more appropriate.

Other classes may be abstract and therefore have no objects, they may still provide some encapsulation.

Template classes could also be though of as being capable of encapsulation even though there will be no objects of the template itself - only objects of "concrete" classes with specific types provided for the templates type parameters.

Also, the word "single" becomes a bit confusing if we apply it to objects since we can have multiple object of a class.

Cid's comment offers an additional reason for "class" over "object".

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a problem with replacing "class" with "object" in the example sentence. It remains valid in class-based OOP languages while being more appropriate for prototype-based OOP languages. Classes are just a type system for OOP after all and not as fundamentally essential as encapsulation is.

I would, however, want to improve that sentence to make it clear that data and functions aren't "wrapped" in the same way. Data must be hidden and only be accessible to methods of an object.

Answer (score 1):

The more important question to consider is why encapsulation is essential to true oop. Objects are to hide their attributes and inner workings, and present an interface for use by other objects. oop begins to break down when this encapsulation is broken. Code becomes harder to maintain if everyone has their hands on everyone else’s data. Consider setters and getters and all the ways we tend to break encapsulation. True object thinking is not primarily about classes and polymorphism. It is definitely about encapsulation and interfacing between objects.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a rough idea of what encapsulation is? So you are asking why couldn't the definition bee rephrased to

> Encapsulation is the wrapping of data and functions into a single unit called an object.

Because encapsulation has nothing to do with objects at all. You can create some class called `Car` and it has some fields like `engine`, `seats`, `steeringWheel` and some methods `applyBrakes`, `openWindow` as well as some private members. Now you can say that the class encapsulates the inner workings of a car into a single unit - the `Car` class.

See? I didn't say anything about objects. `Car` objects are really just a bunch of references in memory pointing to other `Engine`, `Seat` and `SteeringWheel` objects.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, "data" is the problematic term. Classes encapsulate attributes and methods that work on these attributes together. "data" suggests actual data and not meta data. That is probably why you thought of objects instead of classes.

Other than that, I would not replace class with object here, because it leaves out the important feature that all objects from one class have the same methods. With object, one could interpret that each object has its own set of functions.